# How to get a value from a nested object in a GeoJson object in d3js?

Tags: d3.js

I am displaying a simple map with a few polygons (geojson format). These were loaded through the d3.json option.

I am trying to get an alert on mouseover with a value specific to each individual polygon on which I hoover the mouse;

The fact is that by using the examples I saw, (logically) it will not work because I always have an idex of 0 for the geoJson data:

```
function.on("mouseover", function(d,i){ alert(+d3.values(d3.values(d.features[i])[1])[1]); });
```

Because I always have i = 0, the value returned is always the same.

I somehow need to replace the index "i" in the alert posted above with the index of the polygon I am hoovering on.

I have added the full code below. What I am trying to do is to add the San Francisco boundary, then some polygons on top, polygons for which I want to display the value from the column "FINAL" (this value is different foe each polygon).

I have also added a function on mouseover to change the color of the polygon I am hoovering on, but it always changes the color for all the polygons, not just for the one hoovered.

```
<script>
    var svgWidth = 900,
    svgHeight = 900,
    margin = {"top": 25, "right": 25, "bottom": 25, "left": 25},
    width  = svgWidth  - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = svgHeight - margin.top  - margin.bottom;

    var projection = d3.geo.mercator();

    var path = d3.geo.path()
            .projection(projection);
    var svgViewport = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width",  width  + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top  + margin.bottom)
            .style("border", "2px solid");

    // Define Zoom Function Event Listener
    function zoomFunction() {
            d3.selectAll("path")
                    .attr("transform",
                    "translate(" + d3.event.translate
                    + ") scale (" + d3.event.scale + ")");
            }

    // Define Zoom Behavior
    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([0.2, 10])
            .on("zoom", zoomFunction);

    var innerSpace = svgViewport.append("g")
            .attr("class", "inner_space")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
            .call(zoom);

            d3.json("sf_shore.geojson", function(error, us) {
            state = us
            });

            d3.json("for_stack.geojson", function(error, bldg) {
            buildings = bldg;

            projection
                    .scale(1)
                    .translate([0, 0]);

    var b = path.bounds(state),
            s = .95 / Math.max((b[1][0] - b[0][0]) / width, (b[1][1] - b[0][1]) / height),
            t = [(width - s * (b[1][0] + b[0][0])) / 2, (height - s * (b[1][1] + b[0][1])) / 2];

            projection
                    .scale(s)
                    .translate(t);

    innerSpace.append("g").attr("class", "hidden rectangle")
            .append("rect")
            .attr("class", "background")
            .attr("x", function(d, i) { return 0; })
            .attr("y", function(d, i) { return 0; })
            .attr("width", function(d, i) { return width; })
            .attr("height", function(d, i) { return height; })
            .style("fill", "white");

    innerSpace.append("path")
            .datum(state)
            .attr("class", "mesh")
            .attr("d", path);

    innerSpace.append("path")
            .datum(buildings)
            .attr("class", "meshu")
            .attr("d", path)
            .style("fill", function() { return "teal" })
            .on("mouseover", function(e){d3.select(this).style("fill", "gray")})
            .on("mouseout", function(e){d3.select(this).style("fill", "teal")})
            .attr("stroke","white")
            .attr("stroke-width", 0.2);
    });
</script>
```

The data which holds the information I want to display is "for_stack.geojson" and it looks like:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "FINAL": "ID = 0" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -122.408841, 37.807266 ], [ -122.408971, 37.807922 ], [ -122.407742, 37.807404 ], [ -122.408841, 37.807266 ] ] ] } }
,
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "FINAL": "ID = 1" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -122.402690, 37.801356 ], [ -122.402838, 37.802086 ], [ -122.401890, 37.802206 ], [ -122.401776, 37.801613 ], [ -122.401964, 37.801590 ], [ -122.401938, 37.801453 ], [ -122.402690, 37.801356 ] ] ] } }
,
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "FINAL": "ID = 2" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -122.401518, 37.801485 ], [ -122.401660, 37.802229 ], [ -122.400723, 37.802348 ], [ -122.400578, 37.801604 ], [ -122.401518, 37.801485 ] ] ] } }
,
[more features..]
```

Can anyone please advice me how this works?

Thank you for your time,

Comment: `d` refers to the data bound to the polygon you're hovering over. That should contain all features.

Comment: true Sir. I am wondering how it is possible to display the attribute data for the feature you are hoovering on. Like you said, d contains all the data, but somehow I need to get the data only for the feature I am hoovering on.

Comment: No, `d` doesn't contain *all* the data, it contains the data for the feature you're hovering over.

Comment: ok @LarsKotthoff; I am trying and trying but I cannot get hold of the data.

My current position is:

    .on("mouseover", function(d,i){ alert ("Values: " + d3.values(d.features[0])); });

here I get: "Values: Feature,[object Object],[object Object]"
the keys for them are: "Keys: type,properties,geometry"

I think my data of interest is in the "properties" key but as I am new to this I am still trying to figure out how it works.

Comment: Can you post your full code please? What are you binding to the paths and how?

Comment: Sure. Should have done that from the start, sorry. I took out the above mouseover function so you can see a working version. For some reason, I cannot get to the individual values of the polygons when hovering above them. I have always got the same thing for all. Thanks @LarsKotthoff for the help on this code.

Comment: This doesn't look like it would work :) It looks like you're adding a single path for everything -- what you want is to add separate paths, see e.g. http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/

Comment: I thought of this but I also got a bit confused. Thanks for the link, I will start to work on it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Lars Kotthoff I managed to find my way through using two helpful links:

1. http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/
2. https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths

Quote:

Alternatively, you can create multiple distinct path elements:

```
svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.geo.path());
```